# ExtJS Router - Hash links no longer handled like redirectTo()

Tags: extjs

Did something change recently with the way the ExtJS's router handle hash links (i.e. `<a href="#foo/bar">...</a>`)? I have grid cells with hash links in them but they seems to cause the entire page to load now instead of being handled by the router like I'm almost 100% certain they used to be. The same scheme in the [coworkee example](https://examples.sencha.com/coworkee/#people) seems to work but when I do the same in mine, clicking them reloads the entire page.

I'm using the current 7.2.0 release in my code while it appears the [coworkee source](https://github.com/sencha-extjs-examples/Coworkee) is using 7.0.0.  Regression?

Comment: We've recently upgraded to 7.2.0, and we didn't have any router issues... we're using `redirectTo`.  Are your routes using positional or named mode?  Could you possibly set up a Sencha Fiddle demonstrating your issue?

Comment: I use ```redirectTo()``` in controller methods that handle some events like buttons and they work as expected. However, I have links like ```<a href="#foo/id">...</a>``` in grid cells like in the coworkee example I linked above and they cause the entire page to reload. They didn't earlier.

Comment: Right, can you make an example showing us?

Comment: Unable to reproduce it with a small example.  Still digging...